# Angular 2 + ag-grid / Edit entire column

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I would like to edit an entire column with the same value.

I have my ag-grid that looks like this : [image of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g7SM.png)

What I would like to do is to change all the values of the column `Etat` to `arrêté` but I can't make it work for now.

And this is my code with what I tried:

```
private gridOptions: GridOptions;
public rowData: any[];

constructor() {
    this.stopTrains();
    this.gridOptions = {};
    this.gridOptions.columnDef = [
        ...
        {
            headerName: 'Etat',
            field: 'etat',
            ...
            editable: true
        }
        ...
    ];
}

stopTrains() {
    var rowData: any[] = [];
    rowData.push({
        etat: 'arrêté'
    })
    this.rowData = rowData;
}
```

`stopTrains()` is called when I click on a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
stopTrains() {
   //loop through current row data and set the etat key to 'arrêté'
   this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(params=>params.data.etat = 'arrêté')
   //refresh the view so that the changes take effect
   this.gridOptions.api.refreshView()
 }
```

you could also use `forEachNodeAfterFilter` which will only change the visible nodes in the grid.

Here is a plunker for demonstration:

https://embed.plnkr.co/7oj5JXBdwPopgYl751ck/

Comment: I tried `forEachNode` and it works perfectly, thanks !